# Image uploader for Padrino

Tags: ruby, rubygems, paperclip, image-uploading, padrino

I am new at Padrino. 
I created slider model and I want a image uploader as paperclip or other ones for padrino. Who can write or link me step-by-step tutorial for this?

Comment: Where will you be storing the images?  I've used `Dropzone.js` with Padrino to store uploaded files on Amazon S3 with good results. Let me know if you want me to post an answer with some rough step by step instructions.

Comment: I will store them in my server.